# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre String[] y new String[] en c#?

Tags: c#, array

Quisiera saber cuál es la diferencia entre instanciar o no un string[]

Por ejemplo.

```
string[] Ejemplo1 = { "Ejemplo", "Ejemplo2" };
string[] Ejemplo2 = new string[] { "Ejemplo", "Ejemplo2" };
```

¿Cuál es la diferencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad no hay diferencia, si lo realizas de esta forma:

```
string[] Ejemplo1 = { "Ejemplo", "Ejemplo2" };
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

implicitamente estas creando un array de string como esta forma:

```
string[] Ejemplo2 = new string[] { "Ejemplo", "Ejemplo2" };
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

incluso puedes realizar lo mismo de esta forma:

```
  string[] Ejemplo3 = new [] { "Ejemplo", "Ejemplo2" };
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa:

[**Implicitly Typed Arrays**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/implicitly-typed-arrays) (inglés)